# get user images twitter | angular.js | firebase

Tags: facebook, angularjs, twitter, firebase

im quite new to angular.js and firebase, so im starting to edit some code from an open source script to expens my knowledge ... i used a chat script with a facebook login.

i decided to go change the facebook login to a twitter login. (firebase lets you use logins pretty easy)

```
function onLoginButtonClicked() {
  auth.login("Twitter");
}
```

the code also automaticly gets the user image from facebook with

```
<div id="comments">
  <script id="template" type="text/template">
    <img class="pic" src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{userid}}/picture">
    <span><b>{{name}}</b><br/>{{body}}</span>
  </script>
```

But now i changed it to an twitter app i wonder how i can get the twitter user icons instead?

--edit--

whats wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the user info returned from the login process, you'll see that it contains a an object called `thirdPartyUserData`. It contains all of the information provided by twitter during login; this is their purview and could change when their API or policies change in the future, but has (for as long as I've been familiar with the Twitter API) contained URLs for user's avatars:

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(err, user) {
    if( err ) console.error(err);
    console.log('avatar is ', user && user.thirdPartyData.profile_image_url);
});

$('button').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked it');
    auth.login('twitter');
});
```

(Side note: the login provider is `twitter` vs `Twitter`)

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to get the Twitter avatar which works better since getting it from the login user object is only for the logged in user and so would require that the URLs be saved which would then be a problem if the user ever changed their twitter avatar since the URL would then be missing. After some searching around I found that the twitter avatar (or facebook) avatar can be reached from the firebase user id as follows:

```
var info = userId.split(':');
var provider = info[0];
var id = info[1];
if ( provider === 'facebook' ) {
  return 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture?type=square';
} else if ( provider === 'twitter' ) {
  return 'http://twitter.com/api/users/profile_image/' + id + '?size=normal';
}
```